# Ajax does not update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ajax-update

Can you tell me why my ajax does not update both output text fields? In my opinion, it should work well, but unfortunately, it does not.

```
<h:form>      
    &deg;F: 
    <p:spinner value="#{degreeBean.f}" min="32" max="62">
        <p:ajax update="f c"/>
    </p:spinner>
    <h:outputText id="f" value="#{degreeBean.f}&deg;F" />
        = 
    <h:outputText id="c" value="#{degreeBean.c}&deg;C" />
</h:form>
```